# XSLT - How to evaluate a single node in multiple places

Tags: xslt

I am building an image rotator in XSLT that requires the following markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div id="slider" class="slider">
    [IMAGE FROM NODE A GOES HERE]
    [IMAGE FROM NODE B GOES HERE]
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="htmlcaption" class="html-caption">
    [CAPTION FOR NODE A GOES HERE]
    [CAPTION FOR NODE B GOES HERE]
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I need help constructing the XSLT so that Node A would get evaluated inside #slider then get re-evaluated in #htmlcaption, then Node B, and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not enough context.  What are NODE A and NODE B?  I assume the code you showed is the desired output.  What does the input look like?  What XSLT do you already have (SO is not a "give me teh codez" site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is perfectly possible to evaluate a source element multiple times. Just use the same selector.

For example, considering the following XML:

```
<images>
    <node id="a" image="foo.png" caption="foo" />
    <node id="b" image="bar.png" caption="bar" />
</images>
```

This XSLT will repeatedly output stuff from the first node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="images">
    <div id="images">
        <img><xsl:value-of select="node[@id='a']/@image"/></img>
        <img><xsl:value-of select="node[@id='a']/@caption"/></img>
        <img><xsl:value-of select="node[@id='a']/@image"/></img>
        <img><xsl:value-of select="node[@id='a']/@caption"/></img>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<div id="images">
    <img>foo.png</img>
    <img>foo</img>
    <img>foo.png</img>
    <img>foo</img>
</div>
```

However it looks like what you really want is to loop over a bunch of nodes containing image and caption.
You could use a **for-each loop** to avoid selecting the nodes by name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="images">
    <div id="images">
        <xsl:for-each select="node">
            <img><xsl:value-of select="@image"/></img>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <div id="captions">
        <xsl:for-each select="node">
            <div><xsl:value-of select="@caption"/></div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will produce:

```
<div id="images">
    <img>foo.png</img>
    <img>bar.png</img>
</div>
<div id="captions">
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solved my problem precisely. I thought I had tried that approach before but apparently not. I was unsure of how to re-use the same node essentially.

Thanks!